# Unsupported browser using rvest::read_html in the terminal

Tags: r, terminal, rvest

When i run the following code in the terminal:

```
library(rvest)
Scraper <- read_html(url(paste0("https://www.facebook.com/", "Audi.AG","/")))
```

It just gives the following error:

```
{html_document}
<html lang="de" id="facebook" class="no_js">
[1] <head>\n<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8 ...
[2] <body class="unsupportedBrowser x1 Locale_de_DE" dir="ltr">\n<script nonc ...
```

However, if i run it directly in Rstudio it gets the request appropriately.

Comment: 1. "i inspect the content"  is that the html file you get after the Scraper runs? Sounds like your agent is not being set properly and facebook just rejects the request.

Comment: Which part isn't working exactly? It looks like you are getting an HTML response from the server. What exactly were you expecting?

Comment: @abestrad you were right, there is something going on when i run the code from the terminal vs when i run it from Rstudio. Do you have any idea on where fix this :( ?

Comment: Maybe you could try adding the line `options(HTTPUserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0")` before your `read_html` call in Docker?

Comment: It worked! thanks a lot @AllanCameron